# How can I find numbers within specified range of characters in a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

If I have a string `"213_str_12"`. I want to find digits only within first 5 characters so I would get only `212`. Is that possible in bash?

Comment: you mean `213` ?

Comment: To keep only the first 5 characters, you could use `cut`.  To extract numbers you could use `sed`.  You should take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only `bash` you can do

```
s='213_str_12'
f5="${s:0:5}"
echo "${f5//[^0-9]/}"
213
```

`f5` contains the first 5 chars and then replaces all the non-digits to an empty string.

Comment: Is there any way to looping through these files is order? For example, if I have multiple files like `212_str_1.txt`, `212_str_2.txt`, `212_str_3.txt`, `324_str2_1.txt`, `324_str2_2.txt`, `324_str2_3.txt`. I used a for loop to loop through these files but it will read randomly and I am looking for a way to do it in order.

Comment: `ls -1` should produce sorted output